# Azure EventHub publishing with partition key results in Timeout errors

Tags: azure-eventhub

When using EventHubClient.Send(EventData) method I include PartitionKey in the EventData object. We use device's unique ID as a PartitionKey which worked for about a month with increasing traffic. Today suddenly we started receiving constant Timeout exceptions (`System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.`) from the service.

It is required for us to make sure each device data is sent consistently to a single partition to process sequential data.

We want to find out why this is happening and how do we resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the traffic hit a spike for the last period? Have you tried configuring a higher amount of  throughput units? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq

Comment: There was a high traffic yes because we were catching up to the data stream. I have auto scaling turned on (with range 2-4), but not sure if that is enough.